# Почему сравнение строк без учетом регистра менее производительно, чем с учетом?

Tags: c#

Нашел вот такой тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И собственно возник вопрос:

Почему все именно так?

На мой взгляд, разница не должна быть на столько ощутимой.

Comment: Я думаю это все из-за юникода, да и думаю что при проверке без учета регистра, создается копия строки, с преведенным с нижнему, или верхнему регистру массива символов, а возможно и вообще прыгает по таблице символов в поисках анологий.

Comment: @ヒミコ Рихтер, вроде, писал, что происходит приведение к верхнему регистру, так как оно оптимизировано в винде. Но все равно, на мой взгляд, не должно быть такой ощутимой разницы.

Comment: Найти бы вот это [COMNlsInfo::InternalCompareString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,1373), упростило бы задачу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184039/5796587 тут есть интересные мысли на тему того, что по там может использоваться лингвистическое сравнение, а не просто приведение к единому регистру.

Comment: Было бы интересно посмотреть и на исходники, и на подход к измерениям. А так - мало ли что там автор приложения намерял.

Answer (score 6):

Может немного неожиданный ответ, но:

Сравнение строк без учетом регистра менее производительно, чем с учетом регистра потому, что при сравнении без учета регистра нужно применять больше правил при сравнении каждого символа.

В случае Windows в исходники нативного API заглянуть не получится, но .net core, насколько я понял, использует для сравнения [ICU](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu). [Код самого сравнения](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/778d0a6d1d46faa724ead19613bda84621794b72/icu4c/source/i18n/rulebasedcollator.cpp#L968) - там проход по строке с применением правил для каждого символа + пара частных случаев.

Важно то, что метод сравнения строк нельзя выбирать по результатам бенчмарка. Это разные методы, и они дают разный результат на одних и тех же входных данных. Это как сравнивать сложение, деление и интегрирование. Стоит использовать то, что вам нужно. А не использовать всегда Ordinal.

---

К результатам [конкретного бенчмарка, использованного в вопросе](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2017/02/compare-the-performance-of-string-comparison-methods-in-c/) стоит относится с сомнением, т.к. автор бенчмарка допустил сразу все возможные ошибки

- мерял время через `DateTime.Now`
- не привязал тест к конкретной локали
- не учитывал результаты сравнения (оптимизатор потенциально выбрасывает такие тесты в Release)
- использовал данные, на которых некоторые варианты работают заведомо медленнее
- индексировал циклы с 1.

Comment: +1, сравнивать скорость с регистром и без это как сравнивать вкус соленых огурцов и сушеных бананов. Тут не может быть никакого "сравнения"

Answer (score 2):

Провёл бенчмарк с помощью BenchmarkDotnet и получил следующие результаты:

```cs
    [CoreJob, CoreRtJob]
    [RPlotExporter, RankColumn, MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class StringEqualityBenchmark
    {
        [Params(10, 100, 1000, 10_000, 100000)] // размер строки в байтах.
        public int N;

        private string firstString;
        private string secondString;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            {
                var bytes = new byte[N];
                new Random(42).NextBytes(bytes);
                firstString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            }
            {
                var bytes = new byte[N];
                new Random(42).NextBytes(bytes);
                secondString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public bool SimpleEquals() => firstString == secondString;

        [Benchmark]
        public bool ObjectEquals() => object.Equals(firstString, secondString);

        [Benchmark]
        public bool ReferenceEquals() => object.ReferenceEquals(firstString, secondString);

        [Benchmark]
        public bool ToLowerEquals() => firstString.ToLower() == secondString.ToLower();

        [Benchmark]
        public bool ToUpperEquals() => firstString.ToUpper() == secondString.ToUpper();

        [Benchmark]
        public bool InvariantCultureIgnoreCaseEquals() => string.Equals(firstString, secondString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        [Benchmark]
        public bool InvariantCultureEquals() => string.Equals(firstString, secondString, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);

        [Benchmark]
        public bool OrdinalIgnoreCaseEquals() => string.Equals(firstString, secondString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        [Benchmark]
        public bool OrdinalEquals() => string.Equals(firstString, secondString, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        [Benchmark]
        public int StringCompare() => string.Compare(firstString, secondString);

        [Benchmark]
        public int StringOrdinalCompare() => string.CompareOrdinal(firstString, secondString);
    }
```

[image: Результаты]

Из этого всего следует, что самое быстрое сравнение - естественно, по равенству ссылок, добавил в бенчмарк для наглядности.
Использование ToLower и ToUpper почти не отличаются по производительности, где-то одно быстрее, где-то другое. Но оба плохи тем, что создают копию строки, что может быть катастрофично если вызывается часто и/или для больших строк.

Самым лучшим вариантом является использование ordinal ([согласно предложению от MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1309-use-ordinal-stringcomparison?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN))

Игнорирование кейса это дополнительные условия проверки, поэтому она выполняется дольше, но не требует дополнительной памяти, как можно увидеть из результатов бенчмарка.

Для того чтобы понять, что конкретно происходит при сравнении строк, нужно найти исходники для:
`ComNlsInfo::InternalCompareStringOrdinalIgnoreCase`
или 
`ComNlsInfo::InternalCompareString`
т.к. происходит вызов нативного апи